# Код проверок двух постов дублируется - проверку надо вынести в отдельный метод и вызвать в самих тестах

Tags: python, django, dry

Тестирую view. Ревьювер выдал замечание, что "Код проверок двух постов дублируется - проверку можно вынести в отдельный метод и вызвать в самих тестах.". Я думал сократил все что мог и не могу понять как кусок кода надо вывести в отдельный метод. Подскажите пожалуйста на какие строки мне обратить внимание?

```
from http import HTTPStatus

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from ..models import Group, Post
from ..views import MAX_NUMB_ENTRIES

User = get_user_model()
TEMP_NUMB_FIRST_PAGE = 13
TEMP_NUMB_SECOND_PAGE = 3

class PostsPagesTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.author = User.objects.create_user(username='NoName')
        cls.group = Group.objects.create(
            title='test_title',
            description='test_description',
            slug='test-slug'
        )
        cls.post = Post.objects.create(
            text='test_post',
            author=cls.author,
            group=cls.group
        )

def setUp(self):
    self.authorized_author = Client()
    self.authorized_author.force_login(self.author)

def test_pages_uses_correct_template_quest(self):
    """URL-адрес использует соответствующий шаблон для guest_users"""
    templates_pages_names = {
        'posts/index.html': reverse('posts:index'),
        'posts/group_list.html':
            reverse('posts:group_list', kwargs={'slug': self.group.slug}),
        'posts/profile.html':
            reverse('posts:profile', kwargs={'username': self.author}),
        'posts/post_detail.html':
            reverse('posts:post_detail', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.pk}
                    ),
    }
    for template, reverse_name in templates_pages_names.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            response = self.client.get(reverse_name)
            self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)
            self.assertEqual(
                response.context.get('post').id, self.post.pk
            )
            self.assertEqual(
                response.context.get('post').author, self.author
            )
            self.assertEqual(
                response.context.get('post').group, self.group
            )

def test_pages_uses_correct_template_user(self):
    """URL-адрес использует соответствующий шаблон для auth_users"""
    templates_pages_names = {
        reverse('posts:post_create'): 'posts/create_post.html',
        reverse(
            'posts:post_edit', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.pk}
        ): 'posts/create_post.html',
    }
    for reverse_name, template in templates_pages_names.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            response = self.authorized_author.get(reverse_name)
            self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)

def assert_post_response(self, response):
    """Проверяем Context"""
    form_fields = {
        'text': forms.fields.CharField,
        'group': forms.fields.ChoiceField,
    }
    for value, expected in form_fields.items():
        with self.subTest(value=value):
            form_field = response.context.get('form').fields.get(value)
            self.assertIsInstance(form_field, expected)

def test_post_create_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Шаблон post_create сформирован с правильным контекстом."""
    response = self.authorized_author.get(reverse('posts:post_create'))
    self.assert_post_response(response)

def test_post_edit_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Шаблон post_edit сформирован с правильным контекстом."""
    response = self.authorized_author.get(
        reverse('posts:post_edit', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.pk}))
    self.assert_post_response(response)

def test_post_list_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Шаблон post_list сформирован с правильным контекстом."""
    response = self.authorized_author.get(reverse('posts:index'))
    first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
    post_text_0 = first_object.id
    post_author_0 = first_object.author
    post_group_0 = first_object.group
    self.assertEqual(post_text_0, self.post.pk)
    self.assertEqual(post_author_0, self.author)
    self.assertEqual(post_group_0, self.group)


class PaginatorViewsTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.authorized_author = Client()
        cls.author = User.objects.create_user(username='NoName')
        cls.group = Group.objects.create(
            title='test_title',
            description='test_description',
            slug='test-slug'
        )

def setUp(self):
    for post_temp in range(TEMP_NUMB_FIRST_PAGE):
        Post.objects.create(
            text=f'text{post_temp}', author=self.author, group=self.group
        )

def test_first_page_contains_ten_records(self):
    templates_pages_names = {
        'posts/index.html': reverse('posts:index'),
        'posts/group_list.html':
            reverse('posts:group_list', kwargs={'slug': self.group.slug}),
        'posts/profile.html':
            reverse('posts:profile', kwargs={'username': self.author}),
    }
    for template, reverse_name in templates_pages_names.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            response = self.client.get(reverse_name)
            self.assertEqual(
                len(response.context['page_obj']), MAX_NUMB_ENTRIES
            )

def test_second_page_contains_three_records(self):
    templates_pages_names = {
        'posts/index.html': reverse('posts:index') + '?page=2',
        'posts/group_list.html':
            reverse('posts:group_list',
                    kwargs={'slug': self.group.slug}) + '?page=2',
        'posts/profile.html':
            reverse('posts:profile',
                    kwargs={'username': self.author}) + '?page=2',
    }
    for template, reverse_name in templates_pages_names.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            response = self.client.get(reverse_name)
            self.assertEqual(len(
                response.context['page_obj']), TEMP_NUMB_SECOND_PAGE
            )
```

Comment: Очевидно, речь о тестах `test_first_page_contains_ten_records` и `test_second_page_contains_three_records`. Они идентичны с точностью до параметров запроса и ожидаемого результата.

Comment: test_first_page_contains_ten_records и test_second_page_contains_three_records это тесты паджинатора, у них в проверке разные константы (MAX_NUMB_ENTRIES и TEMP_NUMB_SECOND_PAGE) - количество постов на странице). Т.е. это никак не будет мешать если я их в одним метод закину?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как это можно сделать:

```
def _test_pagination(self, url_params, expected_count):
    templates_pages_names = {
        'posts/index.html': reverse('posts:index') + url_params,
        'posts/group_list.html':
            reverse('posts:group_list', kwargs={'slug': self.group.slug}) + url_params,
        'posts/profile.html':
            reverse('posts:profile', kwargs={'username': self.author}) + url_params,
    }
    for template, reverse_name in templates_pages_names.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            response = self.client.get(reverse_name)
            self.assertEqual(
                len(response.context['page_obj']), expected_count
            )


def test_first_page_contains_ten_records(self):
    self._test_pagination("", MAX_NUMB_ENTRIES)

def test_second_page_contains_three_records(self):
    self._test_pagination("?page=2", TEMP_NUMB_SECOND_PAGE)
```

Что касается постов:

```
def _assert_post_has_attribs(self, post, id, author, group):
    self.assertEqual(post.id, id)
    self.assertEqual(post.author, author)
    self.assertEqual(post.group, group)

def test_pages_uses_correct_template_quest(self):
    ...
    for template, reverse_name in templates_pages_names.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            response = self.client.get(reverse_name)
            self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)
            self._assert_post_has_attrs(
                response.context.get('post'),
                self.post.pk,
                self.author,
                self.group
            )

def test_post_list_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Шаблон post_list сформирован с правильным контекстом."""
    response = self.authorized_author.get(reverse('posts:index'))
    first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
    self._assert_post_has_attrs(
        first_object, 
        self.post.pk,
        self.author,
        self.group)
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!  Но дело скорей всего в test_pages_uses_correct_template_quest и  test_post_list_page_show_correct_context. Мне подсказали , что 3 последние проверки в этих методах делают одно и тоже и скорей всего их надо объединить, потому что вопрос ревьювера стоял так "Код проверок двух постов дублируется..." про посты речь была. Вот теперь думаю как это реализовать. Но все равно спасибо Roman за это пример, хороший опыт для меня.

Comment: Спасибо большое, еще раз. Я думаю Ваш код подойдет. Я понял теперь как это делается.